# Original document of the Gaussian integral

Tags: mathematics, calculus

The Gaussian integral

$$\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \exp(-x^2) = \sqrt{\pi} $$

is done in a very smart way. But where is the original document?

Comment: Gauss discovered neither the integral nor the "smart way" to evaluate it.

Comment: You wrote it wrong - you need to indicate the upper and lower bounds. There is no indefinite integral.

Answer (score 6):

At first I voted to close because Wikipedia [clearly attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_polar_coordinates) that “smart way” to **Poisson**. But oddly, the linked document only quotes hearsay by Sturm ([1859](https://archive.org/details/coursdanalysede04prougoog/page/n32)). The actual source is given by Bierens de Haan ([1858](https://archive.org/details/tablesdintegral00haan/page/81), Table 40): Poisson’s *Théorie mathématique de la chaleur* ([1835](https://archive.org/details/thoriemathma00pois/page/139), §74).

(The integral was computed earlier by other methods — see *loc. cit.*, Tables 36 & 37 and [@KCd](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/who-derived-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2/4887#4887).)